# Run function once users mouse leaves text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a text field which users enter data into, once their mouse leaves that text field I want to run a function.

I am aware of the `onBlur` event, but this doesn't run unless the user clicks outside of the field so that doesn't always work as needed. I am also aware of `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` events; but I don't really want to use these as I don't want to run the function more than I need to.

So what other options do I have? Anything in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `mouseleave` event for the `input` only when it is focus'd, and destory it once the event occurs:

JS:

```
$("#txtLeave").focus(function() {
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        console.log("leaving...");
        $(this).off();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s6xf6/2/

Comment: Interesting ! Why do you need the span though ? I mean wouldn't mouseleave work the same on the text box ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov -- And here I was thinking `mouseleave` wouldn't work on `inputs` for some reason, one sec, editing.

Comment: nah mate, it was a genuine question :p I thought you really need the span :) anyway good to know it works like this as well

Comment: This works only first time focus

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method "focusout" ...

```
$('text-field').focusout(function () {
      // ...
});
```

[jQuery focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery supply a method  which execute event once.

```
$("#txt").one("mouseout", function(){
 alert("mouseout"); 
});
```